# Good Schema for DynamoDB and Quantitative Equities Time Series

Tags: database-design, nosql, time-series, amazon-dynamodb

## Problem Statement

What is the most sensible DynamoDB schema (e.g. choosing the composite index and attribute representation) for the following data subject the expected query patterns described below:

## Columns (attributes) for Every Row (item)

I need to store the equivalent of a table with the following columns. Obviously, I am looking for one row per company, factor, and date combination.

1. **Date** (long int) -  in the format `YYYYMMDD`
2. **FactorName** (str) - Something like `"PE"` or `"P/E"`
3. **SecurityID** (str) - Some form of identifier like Bloomberg tickers
4. **Value** (double) - This would the value of the P/E or some other factor for the company

## Volume of Data

I am contemplating approximately 2000 factors, with approximately 20,000 companies per day, 365 days per year, and 20 years. This implies:

1. 7,300 data points per company and factor (365 days/year x 20 years)
2. 40 mln rows for a single cross section (20,000 companies x 2000 factors / company)
3. 20,000 rows for a single factor cross section (20,000 companies, 1 factor, 1 date)
4. 146 mln rows for to hold all values for a single factor across all companies and dates
5. 2.92 x 10^11 total rows (or 292 billions rows)

I have a very efficient solution for a research department using MySQL.  However, what I am working on will NOT scale properly using my prior solution.  Yes, I am aware of NewSQL solutions like Spanner.  I am trying to do this using DynamoDB or BigTable, but I would prefer to know how to do it with DynamoDB.

## Query Patterns

My system will need to execute the following queries at scale.  So, table scanning is NOT at option here.

1. **Cross Section for all Factors** - Retrieving all factors for all companies on a given date
2. **Cross Section for a Single Factor** - Basically, a subset of query 1 above. We want the value of a factor for all companies on a given date.
3. **Time Series for Single Factor and Company** - Basically, given a factor and a company, get the time series. This is useful for plotting a chart such as P/E for a company over time.

## Solution

I would set the following composite index:

1. **Partition Key** - The date **YYYYMMDD**
2. **Sort Key** - FactorName#SecurityID

This should enable query 1 very easily requesting all rows with partition key. One just queries all rows with the given date (e.g. partition key).  It is equally easy to get all values for a given date and factor name by using the `begins_with()` operator on the sort key.  However, this design pattern does not help with query #3.  For example, give me the complete times series of P/Es for a single company.

I have thought about setting `FactorName` as the sort key and creating two attributes (`SecurityID` and `value`) as the item's attributes combined with a secondary index on `SecurityID`.  However, I am not sure if this will result in query 3 being very fast.

An alternative, which I don't like due to space complexity is to denormalize the data, making two copies of the table with different primary keys address the various queries.

## Suggestions

What do you think about my approach?  The design has to serve data to potentially many tens of thousands of customers simultaneously

Yes, I am aware that table duplication with different primary keys might be the solution, but I don't like it.  Yes, I am aware I could use different technologies, but I am exploring NoSQL solutions here.

I am sure you realize that this is basically just one type of the multidimensional query problems that do not fit into the typical time series examples given for Google's BigTable and Amazon's DynameDB.

Thanks much in advance,

Pablo

Comment: The only way to support your third query pattern in DynamoDB is to create a [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html). However, this would roughly double your table storage cost.

Comment: If you are ok with a GSI solution, you can easily support the third query pattern by storing a company name in each record. Then set the composite primary key of the GSI to be a combination of `CompanyName` and `FactorName`. Which one should be the PK or SK doesn't matter here if you don't have other query patterns.

Comment: Thanks much guys.  I was pretty sure this was the case.  I mentioned above secondary index (did not say Global but that is it) on the third dimension or to make a duplicate of the data.

Thanks much to both.

Comment: Yeah, it looks good.